# Aparentemente variável global não armazena o resultado da mysqli_query inteiro

Tags: php

Estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar passar o resultado de mysqli_query por globals, pois só consigo **imprimir na tela** os dados da primeira linha da tabela.
Segue o código:

> função de `class` responsável pelo select:

```
public function select($dataset_name,$entire = True){

    $table = $this->get_table();
    $db_connection = $this->get_db_connection();

    if ($entire == True) {
       $GLOBALS[$dataset_name] = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    }else {
      $array = func_get_args();
      unset($array [0]);
      unset($array [1]);
      $columns = implode(",", $array);
      $GLOBALS[$dataset_name] = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT {$columns} FROM {$table}");
    }
  }
```

> função responsável por imprimir o resultado (PS: Está inacabada, pois falta formatar os dados em uma tabela)

```
<?php
function list_dataset($dataset_name){
  $num_columns = mysqli_field_count($GLOBALS['connection']) - 1;
  $count = 0;

   while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($GLOBALS[$dataset_name])) {

    while ($count <= $num_columns ) {
           echo $array[$count].'</br>';

      $count = $count + 1;

    }
  }
}
?>
```

> O resultado de inserir `print_r(array_keys($GLOBALS)); exit;` antes da
>   função  `mysqli_fetch_array()` é:

```
 Array ( [0] => _GET [1] => _POST [2] => _COOKIE [3] => _FILES [4] => GLOBALS [5] => db_connection [6] => db_action [7] => mysqli [8] => connection [9] => con [10] => teste [11] => select )
```

> **Outras informações:**

- `$GLOBALS['connection']` e  `$GLOBALS[$dataset_name]` coincidem, pois só
  foi feita uma conexão.
- A função `list_dataset()` tem que se adequar à qualquer `select`, se não ela perde o sentido completamente.
- Chamo as funções assim:

> ```
>   $db_connection = new db_connection;
>   $db_connection->set_all('localhost','usuário','senha','db');
>   $db_connection->open();
>   $db_action = new db_action;
>   $db_action->set_all('tabela_usuarios');
>   $db_action->select('teste');
>   $db_action->list_dataset('teste');
> ```

> **Dúvida:** O que estou fazendo errado? Será que estou pondo alguma parte do código no lugar errado?

Comment: O codigo é suscetível a inconsistências. Exemplo, numa mesma rotina tem  `$GLOBALS['connection']` e `$GLOBALS[$dataset_name]`. Se `$dataset_name` não coincidir com `'connection'` pode ser uma causa do erro. Mas pode ter outros motivos diversos.  Para ser mais objetivo, tente um breakpoint ante de chamar `mysqli_field_count()`. Faça assim: `print_r(array_keys($GLOBALS)); exit;` e coloque na pergunta o resultado desse teste.

Comment: @DanielOmine pronto, adicionei o resultado! Quanto a conflitos de conexão, só tem a `'connection'` mesmo! Obrigado, desde já!

Comment: Seria bom você mostrar o código de exemplo em que está chamando as funções para teste.

Comment: Rafael, não há necessidade de colocar "RESOLVIDO" no titulo da pergunta. Você poderia postar a solução como resposta, mas como a pergunta está fechada, o máximo que pode ser feito é você seguir as orientações da caixa amarela para que a pergunta fosse reaberta e ai sim postar a solução como resposta.

Comment: @diegofm certo, obrigado pelo aviso. Não vejo mais o que por para deixar a pergunta mais clara. Se eu não estiver enxergando onde estou errando, por favor me indique. Coloquei a solução na pergunta, tentando deixar o mais claro possível e mostrando que a hipótese inicial estava errada. Não quero que o tópico seja inútil à comunidade, sei que o erro é tolo, mas talvez ajude alguém com erro semelhante.

Comment: Ou então deixar a solução comentário. Se você acha que a solução pode ajudar alguém no futuro, edite a pergunta para ela ficar mais clara. E depois tente que ela seja reaberta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vamos ver se ficou clara, ai ponho nas respostas a solução. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Há muitas coisas erradas, mas vou me abster em comentar os pontos alheios ao objetivo principal da pergunta. Portanto, vamos direto ao ponto.

A função `list_dataset()`, modifique dessa forma:

```
function list_dataset($dataset_name){
    /*
    Note o segundo parâmetro. Defini como MYSQLI_ASSOC. Se preferir, modifique para MYSQLI_NUM. A diferença é que MYSQLI_ASSOC retorna um array associativo, ou seja, a chave de cada array será o nome da coluna da tabela. Com MYSQLI_NUM, os nomes das chaves serão numéricas.

    Consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php


    */
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($GLOBALS[$dataset_name], MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        /*
        id e parent_id são os nomes das colunas da tabela usada para teste.
        modifique para os nomes das colunas da sua tabela 
        */
        echo $data['id'].' - '.$data['parent_id'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Isso é o suficiente para prosseguir.

Caso queira algo mais claro, veja um teste completo:

```
class Foo {
    public function get_db_connection(){
        return new mysqli('localhost', "root", '', 'test');
    }
    public function select($dataset_name,$entire = True){

    $table = 'foo'; // "foo" é nome da tabela que usei para teste. Se quiser pode continuar usando o $table = $this->get_table(); conforme está originalmente.

    $db_connection = $this->get_db_connection();

    if ($entire == True) {
       $GLOBALS[$dataset_name] = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT * FROM {$table}");
    }else {
      $array = func_get_args();
      unset($array [0]);
      unset($array [1]);
      $columns = implode(",", $array);
      $GLOBALS[$dataset_name] = mysqli_query($db_connection,"SELECT {$columns} FROM {$table}");
    }
  }

}

function list_dataset($dataset_name){
    /*
    $GLOBALS[$dataset_name]->num_rows retorna a quantidade de registros encontrados.
    Toda aquela doidera com $count é desnecessária e era a causa principal do problema.
    */
    if ($GLOBALS[$dataset_name]->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($GLOBALS[$dataset_name], MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            /*
            id e parent_id são os nomes das colunas da tabela usada para teste.
            modifique para os nomes das colunas da sua tabela 
            */
            echo $data['id'].' - '.$data['parent_id'].'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'nada encontrado';
    }
}

$c = new Foo();
$c->select('connection', true);
list_dataset('connection');
```

A tabela que usei para testes:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES ('1', '0'), ('2', '1'), ('3', '1'), ('4', '1');
```

Comment: Caro @DanielOmine, eu achei o erro, eu só tinha que zerar o `count` em cada `while` pai do que fazia a contagem. Seguindo sua sugestão, realmente funciona, porém elimino a flexibilidade da função, o que a faria perder sentido, porque ela precisa construir tabelas de qualquer conjunto de dados que for fornecido. Vou depois postar como ficou, muito obrigado pela ajuda!